# Structure 'Decimal' cannot be indexed because it has no default property... But I have options for constants

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Dim intDays As Integer
    Dim decRate As Decimal
    Dim decFinalAmount As Decimal

    Const _cradPenny As Decimal = 0.01D
    Const _cradNickel As Decimal = 0.05D

    If IsNumeric(txtDays.Text) Then
        intDays = Convert.ToInt32(value:=txtDays.Text)

        If intDays >= 10 And intDays <= 22 Then

            If radPenny.Checked = True Then
                decRate = _cradPenny

            ElseIf radNickel.Checked = True Then
                decRate = _cradNickel

            End If

        Else
            MsgBox("Nope, nope. Please enter an amount between 10 and 22.", , "Input Error")
            txtDays.Text = ""
            txtDays.Focus()

        End If

    End If

    decFinalAmount = decRate(intDays - 1) ^ intDays

    lblTotalPay.Text = "Your total pay is " & decFinalAmount.ToString("C")
    lblTotalPay.Visible = True


End Sub
```

I have `decRate` declared, with constants that are determined by the radio button selected.
What am I missing?

I am expecting to run the formula:

```
decFinalAmount = decRate(intDays - 1) ^ intDays
```

Comment: `decRate` is of type `Decimal`, not an array of `Decimal` values to use the indexer notation like so. Apart from that, what is the math equation used to calculate `decFinalAmount`? _t = r * (d - 1) ^ d_ or...?

Comment: If you're trying to multiply then you need to use the multiplication operator.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, there is no implicit multiplication for a(b+c), you have to write a*(b+c). If you write x(y), you might be referring to a method named x that you are passing a parameter y to, or it could be an array x that you want the y-th value of.

Also, it is usually a good idea to [*factor out*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) things like that calculation. You can make sure that that small part of the program functions correctly on its own, and it makes it re-usable without having to type out the formula again.

There are some other parts of VB that you might like to investigate, so here is my take on what you might be able to learn more from:

```
Function CompoundInterestFinalAmount(initial As Decimal, rate As Decimal, paymentPeriodBase As Double, paymentPeriods As Double) As Decimal
    Return CDec(initial * ((1 + rate / paymentPeriodBase) ^ (paymentPeriodBase * paymentPeriods)))
End Function

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Const CRADPENNY As Decimal = 0.01D
    Const CRADNICKEL As Decimal = 0.05D

    ' INTERESTRATE is the actual number, so 5% interest is 0.05D.
    Const INTERESTRATE As Decimal = 0.05D

    Const DAYSMIN As Integer = 10
    Const DAYSMAX As Integer = 22

    Dim days As Integer

    If Int32.TryParse(txtDays.Text, days) Then

        If days >= DAYSMIN AndAlso days <= DAYSMAX Then

            Dim initialAmount As Decimal

            Select Case True
                Case radPenny.Checked
                    initialAmount = CRADPENNY
                Case radNickel.Checked
                    initialAmount = CRADNICKEL
                Case Else
                    MsgBox("Please choose pennies or nickels.")
                    Exit Sub
            End Select

            Dim finalAmount = CompoundInterestFinalAmount(initialAmount, INTERESTRATE, 1, days)

            lblTotalPay.Text = $"Your total pay is {finalAmount:C}."
            lblTotalPay.Visible = True

        End If

    Else
        MsgBox($"Nope, nope. Please enter an amount between {DAYSMIN} and {DAYSMAX}.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Input Error")
        txtDays.Clear()
        txtDays.Focus()

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dr.null - I got the decRate setup as an array and my error was no more!